# How do I get rid of '=' symbols in the email output sent using VB.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I'm using VB.NET to send an email from an ASP.NET form. I'm using a folder to be the destination for the email. Unfortunately, I'm seeing '=' symbols at the end of every line in the message body.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Try
            Dim mailMessage As New MailMessage()
            mailMessage.To.Add("someone@abc.com")
            mailMessage.From = New MailAddress("someone@abc.com")
            mailMessage.Subject = "Subject"
            mailMessage.Body = ("<br>The following query was generated at " + DateTime.Now_+ "<br/><br/>Name : " + TextBox1.Text + "<br/><br/>Email : " + TextBox2.Text + "<br/><br/>Contact Number : " + TextBox3.Text + "<br/><br/>Query : " + TextBox4.Text)

            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = True
            Dim smtpClient As New SmtpClient("localhost")
            smtpClient.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = True
            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage)
            Response.Write(" Email Sent ")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write("Error : " + ex.Message)
        End Try
```

The output is something like this.

```
X-Sender: "Someone" <someone@abc.com>
X-Receiver: Someone@abc.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: "Someone" <Someone@abc.com>
To: Someone@abc.com
Date: 19 May 2015 19:35:49 +0530
Subject: Pink City Queries
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable`

<br>The following query was generated at 19-05-2015 19:35:49<br/>=
<br/>Name : Someone<br/><br/>Email : Someone@abc.com<br/><br/>Con=
tact Number : 0000000000<br/><br/>Query : Hello World!
```

Comment: VB.NET uses `&` for string concatenation. If you use `+` you are open for magic calculations. All the more if you are not using `Option Strict`. You are also using `<br>` at the beginning of the body. Try to always use `<br/>`.

Comment: In general you use `string.TrimEnd` to remove unwanted characters from the end of  a string, for example: `str = str.TrimEnd("="c)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output is entirely correct. There is no need to get rid of anything.

The email is encapsulated in [quoted printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) and in that format `=` means the line breaks are *Soft Line Breaks*.

From the [RFC 2045 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.7):

> (Soft Line Breaks) The Quoted-Printable encoding
> REQUIRES that encoded lines be no more than 76
> characters long.  If longer lines are to be encoded
> with the Quoted-Printable encoding, "soft" line breaks  must be used.  An equal sign as the last character on a
> encoded line indicates such a non-significant ("soft")
> line break in the encoded text.
>
> Thus if the "raw" form of the line is a single unencoded line that
> says:
>
> ```
> Now's the time for all folk to come to the aid of their country.
> ```
>
> This can be represented, in the Quoted-Printable encoding, as:
>
> ```
> Now's the time =
> for all folk to come=
>  to the aid of their country.
> ```

You can verify this with an email client or online [here](http://www.convertstring.com/EncodeDecode/QuotedPrintableDecode).